# Slack webhook in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slack

I am opening a Rails console to try and use HTTParty to send a message to a slack channel using web hooks.

It all works when I use Postman but it doesnt work when I try HTTParty.  In Postman I simply POST to the url with form-data with a `key` of `payload` and a `value` of:

```
{"channel" => "#some_channel", "username" => "webhookbot", "text" => "Testing message", "icon_emoji" => ":ghost:"}
```

In the rails console I am trying:

```
HTTParty.post(webhook_url, body: {"channel" => "#some_channel", "username" => "webhookbot", "text" => "Testing message", "icon_emoji" => ":ghost:"}, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

I get this error message:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "hooks.slack.com" port 443
```

Is this a proxy issue?

Comment: Have you tried using "payload" instead of "body"?

Comment: yes i tried that and it didnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HTTParty.post(webhook_url,
  body: {
    "channel" => "#some_channel",
    "username" => "webhookbot",
    "text" => "Testing message",
    "icon_emoji" => ":ghost:"
  }.to_json,
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }
)
```

Comment: still getting rrno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "hooks.slack.com" port 443   - I can't undertsand why it works fine in Postman and not in a rails console.  Is the request not 100%?

Comment: Try it with the "verify: false" flag set.

Comment: Also, this gem makes doing slack notifications super easy: https://github.com/stevenosloan/slack-notifier

Comment: I just tried this gem and i got the same error - I wonder what would be different in a rails console, some sort of network or proxy issue?

Comment: Wow that is strange. If you have the means, try tethering to your phone and see if you still get the same error. If you do then it's likely something local to your computer (like openssl). If it works then you'll know it's some problem on your local network.

Comment: Can you try to use a http://requestb.in URL instead of Slack for the webhook URL to verify that it is working with another (non https) domain ?